# Should TS catch this bug with return a subclass from a constructor?

Tags: typescript, static-members

When a superclass constructor returns the constructor for a subclass, should TS be preventing name clashes between static and instance properties?

Hopefully the question will make sense with this example:

```
class Base {
  constructor() {
    return Derived;
  }
}

class Derived extends Base {
  x = 1;
  static x = "string"; // should error on the type mismatch here

  constructor() {
      super();
  }
}

const result = new Derived();
Derived.x = "hello";
// is really a string at runtime, but TS errors
// because it thinks `result.x` is a number 
const x: string = result.x
```

[playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQ1rAPYDsIBcAnAV2Hy0IAoBKFdDaQhfYwnaAEQUIEsA3BABMA3PQC+qCalCQYXXgMHQEAD3wIcgmPAhI0GFdAC80AIyiMBMPh7BohkwCICvHAHNHw6AHpv0CAAWWMQgStyEFNC40PgBSPgAngAOSAC2PBCp1sAB0HFMqPTYeESk5FS0+gyWxCkVFtASUsUEjAgQIfjG0DgIAO6c3PxCNKLyw4IAdA7QjnEgIFieqL7QGW1gCwnQYP5EPO47XSQ4NqkI0ritKgBce65u3b0D44o000A)

I adapted the example from a discussion of [ES class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/issues/256#issuecomment-511198458).

Comment: Did you mean `return new Derived` from Base's `constructor`?

Comment: Am I missing something? `new Derived().x` is not a string a runtime. It will return `1`. And why should `static x = "string";` result in a type mismatch? Static and instance properties are different.

Comment: Whoops! I updated the last line. Now `x` is a string. In this case, the static and instance properties are on the same object, since `Base`'s constructor returns `Derived`. Works in Chrome Canary if you remove the type annotation on the last line.

Comment: But, your last line does have a type error… And why should the definition of `static x` have a type error? Static and instance properties are not the same thing. Further, the return value of a constructor is not used.

Comment: Static properties are properties on the *constructor*, and instance properties are properties on *each instance of the class*.  The class constructor is generally not itself an instance of the class, just as a baker is generally not a cake.

Answer (score 1):

To find the answer to your questions you need to understand two things

1. whatever you return from a constructor is not stored as the output of new operator, whenever you write `new ClassName()` it will be the context created
2. the two properties `x` you put are different one is static and other is instance property

See comments added in your code

```
class Base {
  constructor() {
    return Derived;// no meter what you return from here new will return context
  }
}

class Derived extends Base {
  x = 1;
  static x = "string"; // should error on the type mismatch here

  constructor() {
      super();
  }
}

const result = new Derived();
Derived.x = "hello"; // static property x
// is really a string at runtime
const x: string = result.x // instance propery x
``
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I'm confused about how this relates to my question. I'm asking if TS should be catching the type mismatch (string and number)

Comment: It will catch for sure your static variable is string and you can only assign string to it otherwise you will get compilation errors, similar instance variable x can. Only be assigned number